# Function to calculate hours in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to create a  function in SQL server 2008 R2 which returns Non-OverTime hours(Non-OT) when 2 parameter @ShiftStart and @ShiftEnd passed. The Overtime hours are fixed between 22:00 hrs - 06:00 hrs. We want Non-OT hours which is not in these OT hours.
Few cases and the result shown below.

```
Case No          ShiftStart               ShiftEnd                   Non-OT Hours
1.        '2017-12-28 05:00:00.000'  '2017-12-28 08:00:00.000'      2 calculated like this (06:00 - 08:00)
2.        '2017-12-28 20:00:00.000'  '2017-12-28 23:00:00.000'      2 calculated like this (22:00 - 20:00)
3.        '2017-12-28 22:00:00.000'  '2017-12-29 01:00:00.000'      0 as this shift is inside the OT hours
4.        '2017-12-28 20:00:00.000'  '2017-12-29 02:00:00.000'      2 calculated like this (22:00 - 20:00)
```

Please help in writing the function
fn_GetNonOTHours(@ShiftStart,@ShiftEnd)

Thanks

Comment: Please show what you have tried, any problems you face. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. You need to show what you have achieved so far and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE FUNCTION fn_GetNonOTHours
(
 @ShiftStart datetime
 , @ShiftEnd datetime
)
RETURNS  int
AS
BEGIN
-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE @cnt int

Declare @CurrentStart datetime, @CurrentEnd datetime

Select @CurrentStart=DATEADD(HOUR,6,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ShiftStart), 0)),
@CurrentEnd=DATEADD(HOUR,-2,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @ShiftStart)+1, 0))

;with cte as(
Select case when @ShiftStart<@CurrentStart then @CurrentStart else @ShiftStart end as StartHours,
    case when @ShiftEnd>@CurrentEnd then @CurrentEnd else @ShiftEnd end as EndHours )

Select @cnt=DATEDIFF(HOUR,StartHours,EndHours)  from cte

RETURN @cnt

END

create table #test (   CaseNo int,         ShiftStart datetime, ShiftEnd  datetime)
 Insert into #test values
(1,'2017-12-28 05:00:00.000','2017-12-28 08:00:00.000') 
,(2,'2017-12-28 20:00:00.000','2017-12-28 23:00:00.000')
,(3,'2017-12-28 22:00:00.000','2017-12-29 01:00:00.000')
,(4,'2017-12-28 20:00:00.000','2017-12-29 02:00:00.000')

Select *, dbo.fn_GetNonOTHours(ShiftStart, ShiftEnd) Non_OT_Hour from #test